# Android app crashes when the .xml file for animation is being called

Tags: android

I have this simple .xml file called "fadein.xml" to animate an image...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">


    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" 
        duration="2000"/>

</set>
```

And here is how I am referring to this animation file from my main java class...

```
    ImageView logo;
    Animation myFadeInAnimation;

    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoImage);
    myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    logo.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
```

However my app crashes every time this part is supposed to run....can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

***EDIT***

here is the logcat log....

```
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloandroid2/com.example.helloandroid2.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at com.example.helloandroid2.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:28)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
11-03 22:26:37.579: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1558):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Show logcat output. And check `logo` not null before calling `startAnimation`.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski: I have added the logcat trace. And jamapag, I am pretty sure that it is not null.

Comment: Paste the code at this point at com.example.helloandroid2.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:28) . Including line 28 in SplashScreen class.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem that you are experiencing. i just used a method that calls the animation when needed anywhere in or out of the class with this method:

```
public void animate(X a){

Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
a.startAnimation(myFadeAnimation);
}
```

//where X is the type you want to animate like `View` for android widgets like imageViews, buttons, textViews that you want to animate. To call this, simply type type the method `animate(logo)` like that. hope it worked for your case!

don't forget to delete all the animation declarations above. This method does all the work. :D